# IPython dashboard not displaying properly

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I just installed Python recently and when I try to access the IPython dashboard it doesn't display properly and I can't open a new notebook. I took a screenshot, see below. I believe it might have something to do with the fact that the path in which I saved Anaconda has a non Acsii character (é). However when I try to install it somewhere else it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Philippe, it seems that notebook cannot load required CSS and JS libraries. You are getting bare unstyled HTML output. Indeed, "é" character or **spaces** in the path might cause it. You may load webmaster tool for your browser (e.g. Firebug) and analyze what files are failed to load. [Here is](http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci571/Special/Tutorials/firebug-571.pdf) a short tutorial. Many more are easily googled.

Alternatively, just reinstall your distribution into default `C:\Anaconda` path.

EDIT: fixed the link

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are not using your host ip address. The 127.0.0.1:8888 is just the example given in the instructions. Ipython works by putting in your system's host address which can be found by using ifconfig for Linux or ipconfig for windows in your command line. The host address should be the ip listed next to "inet addr: #.#.#.#"